# How to compare two or more values ( not consecutive) in the same column google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, compare

I want to compare two values in the same columns in google apps script to get a specific cell, but I've failed to do it.

Here's the code i've tried, and I will put you the screen of my data test.

Thank you in advance.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
      var lr = ss.getLastRow();

      for (i = 2; i < lr +1; i++){

        var store =data[i][0];

        if (data[i][0] == data[i+1][0]) {

          var total = data[7][5];

          logger.log(total)
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: A2,A5,A11,A8 are equal. Then what? How did E8 come into play?

Comment: @Themaster, Thank you for your reply. The conditions is: If A2,A5,A11,A8 are equal then I need the value of E8. How can I do that on the google apps script? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare A2 against A5,A11,A8, use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)  and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const isEqual = (e1,e2) => e2.map(row => data[row-1][0]).every(e => e === data[e1-1][0]);
console.log(isEqual(2,[5,11,8]));
if(isEqual(2,[5,11,8])) return data[8-1][4];
```

Comment: I have another question please, what about in general case ? I'll try to clarify to you. In my case, I don't know where '400' is located (and I need to search other lines which contains the value '400'). I've more than 500 lines … How we can do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: You could try to use textFinder

Comment: @Riad Basically, you'd loop through. If you're just looking for `400`, in your question:  change from `if (data[i][0] == data[i+1][0])` to  `if (data[i][0] === 400)`  Note however that, It would be preferable to ask new questions for follow up questions.

Comment: @Riad Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of this post.

Comment: @TheMaster done , I didn't knew it. Thank you